# How do online division rewards work?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

Each day, division activities are tallied and members of the most active divisions  are able to select from a list of rewards depending on their division's standing. I want to know how I can get the most out of this feature, so I was wondering how can I improve my own division's standing. What rewards should I be aiming for, and is there any deterrent to switching to the most active division?

Comment: This is similar to another of my questions about divisions, but this one is focused on the **online** aspect of them, whereas my other question is focused on the **offline** aspect. They're fairly separate, so I went with two questions rather than one Frankenstein's monster of a question.

Comment: For completeness, and to make the questions appear in each others' linked section: the other question is [How do the divisions work?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/246932/how-do-the-divisions-work).